# Running python file through VS Code terminal

Tags: python

My question is I am unable to run a python file in VS Code terminal unless I specify the full path.
Whereas, when I see any python tutorial, only python filename is entered and it works.
Can somebody pls help me with this issue?

Comment: cd to the code folder and try running python code with the filename

Comment: What OS are you using? Also, are you in the same directory as the Python file?

Comment: @cocomac I'm using Windows 10. I wasn't before but now I am in the same directory so it's working. Thanks.

Comment: @Deepan how do I cd to the code folder? Sorry I am a complete beginner

Comment: share screenshot of the vscode terminal where you ran the code successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files need to be in the same folder where you are operating / or have the other Python files.

You can use two ways for this:

first:

```
import os
pwd = os.getcwd()

# again, make sure you file is in the same directory. 

the_file = (pwd + "\\filename.xlsx")
```

or Secondly,

```
#the below you can use wherever your file is and it will locate it. 
# you specify the full path using pathlib.path and:
pathlib.path(directory here without the file itself).joinpath(file name here).
```

Comment: I understand. Thank you:)  btw how can I learn more about working with files in Python? Is there a good website I can use?

Comment: I would recommend watching Youtube videos , but if you have the money, I also recommend some courses on Coursera or Udemy regarding Python. I used them and they were helpful for me. also, if this answered your question, please check the check mark so we can close this question.